# The compiler cannot find the attributes in the app.config

Tags: c#, config

The compiler cannot find the attributes in the app.config(He throws a SettingsPropertyNotFoundException ).
Here is the Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigurationFile settings = new ConfigurationFile();
        settings.SoundFile = "ring.wav";
        settings.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        settings.Save();
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
sealed internal partial class ConfigurationFile : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    public string SoundFile
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string) this["SoundFile"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["SoundFile"] = value;
        }
    }

    public global::System.Drawing.Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return ((global::System.Drawing.Color) this["Background"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["Background"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

I first thought i would have picked other names than in my app.config file but they are same. This is the first time I work with the app.config so I guess I do anything wrong. I would be nice if anyone could help me.

Comment: Two possibilities here : 1_ the app can't access the settings file because of permissions issue. 2_ the app expect to find the settings file under root folder but it doesn't. Try to find the file in the root path if it does exist.

Comment: Does the app.config file actually exist in the location the application is expecting it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings you are trying to use are Project settings which is different from the Application configuration settings. 
Also you need to mark the properties with either one of the attribute:

```
[System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSetting]
public string SoundFile
```

// OR

```
[System.Configuration.UserScopedSetting]
public string SoundFile
```

The save will only save changes in your Settings.settings under Properties section in your project.

Application configuration settings can be accessed via (You also need to add reference to System.Configuration assembly in your project):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoundFile"];
```

If you want to use ApplicationConfiguration in your configuration file then you can do something like:

```
    public string SoundFile
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoundFile"];
        }

        set
        {
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoundFile"] = value;
        }
    }
```

It won't save the values to the file but will keep the updated values during the current session.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work with settings this way. If you [right click on your project -> Add -> New Item -> Settings File  (Settings1.settings will be the default name) -> configure your properties] you can further work with it like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Settings1.Default.Background = Color.Red;
    Settings1.Default.SoundFile = "ring.wav";
    Settings1.Default.Save();
    Console.WriteLine("finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```